# Prove that if one of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }{f(x)}$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x^3)}$ exists, then the other one also exists.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if one of $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }{f(x)}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x^3)}$ exists, then the other one also exists. Can anyone guide me on this ? I have no idea on how to start .

Comment: Just note that $x\longrightarrow 0$ if and only if $x^3\longrightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\lvert x^3 \rvert \le \delta^3$, with $\delta \le 1$, then $\lvert x \lvert \le \delta$ too. So you can go through the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ dance for one and the other in parallel with minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x^3)}$ exists

Need to prove if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x^3)}$ exists
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x^3)}$$

Let $y = x^3$, then if $x\to0$, $y\to0$ 
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}{f(y)}$$
But given $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}$ exist so $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x^3)}$ also exist

In similar way Consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}$ exists 
Need to prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}$ exists

Let $y = x^{1/3}$, then if $x\to0$, $y\to0$

so we have
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}{f(y^3)}$$
But $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)}$ exists so $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}{f(y^3)}$ also exists

Comment: i guess there are a lot of typos?